# How to install a Java program from source

Tags: java, software-sources, source

How I can install TubeMaster++ from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tubemaster/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just download it from sourceforge
2. extract .zip using the following command line at terminal :

   `unzip ~/Downloads/TubeMaster%2B%2B.2.5_Source.zip`
3. open eclipse (install it if already not installed: `sudo apt-get install eclipse`)
4. go to eclipse menu: open project and select the directory

   `~/Downloads/TubeMaster++.2.5_Source`
5. Then build

I  hope that helps